# Mac OS X - How can you make a page control similar to the one found in iPhone in Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, uipagecontrol

How can you make a page control similar to the one found on the iPhone, but for the Mac OS?

Something that has a couple of views and allows you to switch between them by pressing on "Next" and "Back".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way: create an NSTabView, and set the tabs to hidden. Then you can call `selectNextTabViewItem:` or `selectPreviousTabViewItem:` on it (wire your next and back buttons up to these methods).

Comment: Even easier: don't hide the tabs and have a normal Macintosh interface.

Comment: @LaC very handy if you want to show thousands of photos. However, a collection view would be better in that case.